# Pyinstaller Matplotlib [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI142562\\matplotlib\\mpl-data\\matplotlibrc'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I want to make a standalone exe with pyinstaller.

If I execute the .exe file I get the following Error:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\invpepeshort>.\invpepe.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "invpepe.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 820, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 725, in _rc_params_in_file
  File "contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 703, in _open_file_or_url
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI142562\\matplotlib\\mpl-data\\matplotlibrc'
```

I hope someone can suggest a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's the most correct answer, but I had the exact same problem as you.

For me solved, re-installing the Pyinstaller version develop

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip